# Avoid downloading from local ressource with valid URI. URI with Implicit or Explicit file path

Tags: c#, download, uri

Using [System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile) Method. I can download a file from a specified URI.

My issue is that an URI might be directed to a valid Local File:

- "C:/Directory/FileName.ext"
- "../../Directory/FileName.ext"

I would like those File path to be either Invalid URI or to force WebClient to only to Http/Ftp.

```
foreach(var link in inputs){
    Download(link)
}

void Download(string source)
{
    var uri = new URI(source);

    //Stop me from downloading from local file

    var response = webClient.DownloadData(uri); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look to the [Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.scheme?view=netframework-4.8) property of the `Uri`.

It:

- Is the string `http` for uri's build with paths like `http://www.test.com/index.html`
- Is the string `file` for uri's build with paths like `c:\test.txt`
- Throws `InvalidOperationException` for relative uri's

With the help of the [IsAbsoluteUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.isabsoluteuri?view=netframework-4.8) property, you can filter uri's like that:

```
var scheme = uri.IsAbsoluteUri ? uri.Scheme : null; // can be put in a SchemeOrNull extension method
if (acceptedSchemes.Contains(scheme))  // acceptedSchemes contains "http", "ftp", ..
{
  ...
```